# How does Spring's @Scheduled actually work?

Tags: java, spring, aop

I always thought that `@Scheduled` works by proxying the whole bean, same way the `@Async`, `@Transactional`, etc does.
So I was surprised that the following works like a charm:

```
    @Component
    public static class Bean {

        @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
        private void scheduled() {
            System.out.println("Yo");
        }
    }
```

Did they change something or it's how it was from the very beginning?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In a few words, with the simplest possible configuration, when Spring detects `@EnableScheduling` annotation it creates a new `ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` which is able to process the `@Scheduled` annotations. After finding the `@Scheduled` annotations using reflection, it will read their configuration and then it will register them in order to be invoked by `TaskScheduler`. A `ScheduledTaskRegistrar` is used to help submit task to the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`.

As you can see, no proxy is being created.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. It seems a bit confusing to me, though. I mean you expect it to be consistent with others. Anyway, I guess it makes sense to avoid unnecessary proxies when possible.